# Function updates all objects in array bound with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a container with data that is loaded dynamically.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let timeSheet of timeSheets ;trackBy: trackId; let i = index;">
    <tr *ngIf="!timeSheet.client.exitDate || compareDate(timeSheet.client.exitDate, selectedDate)==1">
        <td>{{timeSheet.client.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{timeSheet.client.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{timeSheet.client.exitDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
        <td class="hours-column"><input name="hoursLogged" [(ngModel)]="timeSheets[i].hoursLogged" type="number" (change)="calculate(i)" /></td>
        <td class="hours-column">
            <input name="payment" type="number" [(ngModel)]="timeSheets[i].payment" value="{{timeSheets[i].payment}}"/>
            <div *ngIf="!timeSheets[i].plausible">Nope</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

It is basically a list of time sheets to filled in. The basic information is displayed and then the user can enter an amount if hours (-> hoursLogged) and then the calculate() method is called, to automatically filled in the amount to be paid:

```
calculate(index) {
    console.log("updating index: " + index);
    this.timeSheets[index].payment = (5 * this.timeSheets[index].hoursLogged);
}
```

Now here's where it's get problematic:

Whenever I enter some hours in one field, all the payment fields get filled out, too, despite the fact that I bound the payment field using

```
[(ngModel)]="timeSheets[i].payment"
```

[image]

So my question is: why are all the fields being updated when I specifically bind the respective element of the object and also specifically call the calculate() function for said element?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: please create a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz :)

Comment: Make the names for each input unique. That is the only possible issue which i can see. Can you provide a demo?

Comment: @Arcteezy Yaah, I think the issue is the exactly that but didn't want to say this, since we really need MCVE to make the proper diagnosis ;) I suspect this code is inside a form tag, that would definitely cause this issue.

Comment: Yes, it is in a form tag. I'm trying to come up with a demo, working on it :)

Comment: Never mind, naming the field name="payment_{{i}}" actually did the trick. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to users Arcteezy and AJT_82, the following did solve the this problem:

The field names need - of course - to be unique. So here's what worked (in case somone stumbles across this question:

```
<input name="payment_{{i}}" type="number"[(ngModel)]="timeSheets[i].payment" value="{{timeSheets[i].payment}}"/>
```